# Why Jones vector can describe partially polarized light?

Tags: optics, polarization

I have read that polarized light is treated by Jones vectors and that to treat partially polarized light you have to use Stokes vectors.
But in some treatment I saw the Jones vector $E=[\sqrt{\frac{1+d}{2}},\sqrt{\frac{1-d}{2}}]^\intercal$ be used to describe a partially polarized light with degree of polarization $d$.
I want to know the reason.
The paper that treat partially polarized light with Jones vectors is https://spie.org/Publications/Proceedings/Paper/10.1117/12.726615

Comment: here is the link :https://spie.org/Publications/Proceedings/Paper/10.1117/12.726615